# MySQL - Find rows matching all rows from joined table

Tags: mysql, join

Table 1: Tracks

Table 2: Wordlist

Table 3: N:M Track has Words (trackwords)

Find all tracks which have all the words.

currently the query looks like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.id FROM track as t
Left Join trackwords as tw ON t.id=tw.trackid
Left Join wordlist as wl on wl.id=tw.wordid
WHERE 
wl.trackusecount>0 
group by t.id
HAVING SUM(IF(wl.word IN ('folsom','prison','blues'),1,0)) = 3;
```

Which according to EXPLAIN is using all indexes neccessary:

```
+----+-------------+-------+--------+-----------------------+---------+---------+----------------+---------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | type   | possible_keys         | key     | key_len | ref            | rows    | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+-----------------------+---------+---------+----------------+---------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | t     | index  | PRIMARY               | PRIMARY | 4       | NULL           | 8194507 | Using index | 
|  1 | SIMPLE      | tw    | ref    | wordid,trackid        | trackid | 4       | mbdb.t.id      |       3 | Using where | 
|  1 | SIMPLE      | wl    | eq_ref | PRIMARY,trackusecount | PRIMARY | 4       | mbdb.tw.wordid |       1 | Using where | 
+----+-------------+-------+--------+-----------------------+---------+---------+----------------+---------+-------------+
```

But the query takes ages.
Any suggestion to speedup the query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem set is very much like that of storing tags for an item like StackOverflow or Del.icio.us does.

The article [Tags: Database schemas](http://web.archive.org/web/20060204100612/http://www.pui.ch/phred/archives/2005/04/tags-database-schemas.html) proposes several solutions, among them @ChssPly76's idea.

Comment: Except that the link is dead now.

Comment: i found the new link for it.

Answer (score 5):

There's no point in left joins if you're only looking for tracks that have all the words. I'm assuming that (`trackid`,`wordid`) combination is unique in `trackwords`.

```
SELECT t.id
  FROM track as t,  trackwords as tw, wordlist as wl
 WHERE t.id=tw.trackid
   AND wl.id=tw.wordid
   AND wl.trackusecount>0 /* not sure what that is - you have it in your query */
   AND wl.word in ('folsom','prison','blues')
 GROUP by t.id
HAVING count(*) = 3
```

This query would benefit from indexes on wordlist(word), trackwords(trackid,wordid) and track(id).

Comment: your query is using a temptable which makes it 3 times slower.

but nevermind, your having count() = 3 is a a good idea und brings me to: 
SELECT DISTINCT t.name, t.id FROM track as t Left Join trackwords as tw ON t.id=tw.trackid Left Join wordlist as wl on wl.id=tw.wordid WHERE  wl.trackusecount>0  AND wl.word IN ('folsom','prison','blues') group by t.id HAVING Count(t.id) = 3 LIMIT 0,10;
which is nearly 10times faster then my orginal query :)

Comment: It should not use a temp table if you have appropriate indexes defined. You'll have 3 rows in wordlist, index lookup on trackwords and index lookup on tracks

Comment: strange, in some cases your version is faster, in some cases mine is faster.

(taking different words to test, query cache is strong in this case :-)

btw. your solution is the same as mentioned on the link from thinkzig. so i guess its right :-)

Comment: explain says so: 
 PRIMARY,word,trackusecount | word    | 767     | NULL            |    2 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort

Comment: gave the accepted answer to thinkzig, dont be mad, just giving a newb like me some points :-)

Comment: I don't get mad, I get even. Joking, of course :-) thinkzig's article is very detailed. As far as explain you've posted goes - perhaps you're selecting additional columns in that query? Or you don't have the indexes I've mentioned?

Comment: Just stumbled on this an it seems to work for me. However, my joins no longer work like this. I assume because of the multiple tables I'm selecting from. Mysql can't find the columns I want to join on (they exist, worked before I added the multiple tables-FROM). Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Would probably be faster if you broke this up into two queries. First, a join of the words and trackwords to net you all the trackids you need. Then go back to the track table and do:

```
WHERE t.id IN(...trackids here...)
```

but based on the query above all you're returning is t.id which you have from tw.trackid already.

Comment: theoreticly right, but i shortend the SELECT part of the query to make it easier to understand :)

i tried this with seperated queries, and sub selects, all versions were slower :(