# Finding ID having all values (mySQL, SQL)

Tags: sql, mysql

Think about a table like this

```
ID     Value    
100    1    
100    3    
101    1    
101    4    
102    2    
102    5    
103    2    
103    4    
104    1    
104    3    
105    2    
105    5
```

The problem is, if I give values 2 and 5 I should get 102 and 105 which both 102 and 105 are having values 2 and 5 at the same time or if I give values 1 and 3 I should get 100 and 104.

How can I do this with only one sql command? I need a query as light as possible.

and using UNION, INTERSECTION or NESTED SQLs, which one is faster, slower, heavier e.t.c?

Thanks in advance
Ergec

Comment: Thank you guys, I started to test queries to find the fastest and the lightest one.

It seems that Rufinus's query is the fastest.

20,000 records, 1006 results
Jhonny average 0.0045 seconds
David average 0.0020 seconds
Rufinus average 0.0010 seconds (I'd never think doing in this way :))

I am open to new suggestions

Comment: Even tough Rufinus' answer is the fastest I'd select David's answer. Its fast enough and flexible so I can group values with ANDs and ORs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's lots of solutions. Addition to the Jhonny's solution, you can use a join

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.id
FROM table t1, table t2
WHERE t1.id = t2.id
  AND t1.value = 2
  AND t2.value = 5
```

OR use Intersect

```
SELECT id FROM table WHERE value = 2

INTERSECT

SELECT id FROM table WHERE value = 5
```

Answer (score 7):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT id
  FROM test
WHERE 
   value in (2,5)
GROUP by id
HAVING count(*) = 2
```

If you want to test it, simple table for it (with no indexes!):

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test (
  id int(4) NOT NULL,
  `value` int(4) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO test (id, value) VALUES
(100, 1),
(100, 3),
(101, 1),
(101, 4),
(102, 2),
(102, 5),
(103, 2),
(103, 4),
(104, 1),
(104, 3),
(105, 2),
(105, 5);
```

I had a very similar question a few days ago. see [MySQL - Find rows matching all rows from joined table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1242223/mysql-find-rows-matching-all-rows-from-joined-table)

Answer (score 0):

This would be my way to achieve it:

```
SELECT DISTINCT id
FROM table 
WHERE 
id IN (SELECT id FROM table WHERE value = 2)
AND 
id IN (SELECT id FROM table WHERE value = 5)
```