# Finding all ID having all values from other table

Tags: mysql

In three tables:

```
Actors:
+------------------+
| id_a | actor_name|
+------------------+
|   1  | AAA       |
|   2  | Bbb       |
|   3  | Ccc       |
|   4  | Ddd       |
|   5  | Eee       |
+------------------+

Movies:
+----------------+
| id_m | mov_name|
+----------------+
| 1    |   LoR   |
| 2    |  Thron  |
| 3    |   ZsT   |
+----------------+

actors_in_movies:
+-------------+
| id_m | id_a |
+-------------+
| 1    |  1   |
| 1    |  3   |
| 1    |  5   |
| 2    |  1   |
| 2    |  3   |
| 3    |  2   |
| 3    |  3   |
| 3    |  4   |
| 3    |  5   |
+-------------+
```

Is possible to write one query to get: all movies where actors from query play ?

Example:  SELECT id_m WHERE id_a IN (1,3,4,5), should give:

```
+------+
| id_m |
+------+
|  1   |
|  2   |
+------+
```

however.. SELECT id_m WHERE id_a IN (1,9) should give NULL.

I tried similar queries: [Finding ID having all values (mySQL, SQL)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1254854/finding-id-having-all-values-mysql-sql), writing something like:

```
SELECT id_m, count(*), group_concat(id_a) as all_act 
FROM actors_in_movies 
WHERE
 id_m IN (SELECT id_m FROM actors_in_movies WHERE id_a = 1)
AND
 id_m IN (SELECT id_m FROM actors_in_movies WHERE id_a = 3)
AND
 id_m IN (SELECT id_m FROM actors_in_movies WHERE id_a = 5)
GROUP BY (id_m)
HAVING count(*) <= 3
```

it show only one movie (id_m: 1),
if i use 'OR' it's almost OK,
but it's important to me to get all movies where actors from query play,
quered actors or less, never movies that have actors missed in query.
How it should be written ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `group by` and `having`:

```
SELECT id_m
FROM table
WHERE id_a IN (1, 9) 
GROUP BY id_m
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT id_a) = 2;
```

Comment: it works, but if i try search for id_a IN `(1, 3, 9, 12, 13, 14)` i didn't get result `id_m:2` what desired. If i change `having` to `<=6` i get all movies which have at least one id from query..

Comment: but i need movies containing all ids from query or less, if movie have more actors than listed in query it shouldn't be in results